# Which Numbers Would Crash this Function?

Tags: c, programming-puzzle, division

Which values of x and y will cause a crash with some C compilers?

```
int f(int x, int y) {
    return (y==0) ? 0 : (x/y);
}
```

Comment: Since C's ternary operator shortcuts, I would say none would.  This question doesn't seem to fit the format for this site, which is focused on program puzzles and code golf.  See the faq for details http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq.

Comment: This isn't code golf, but is a puzzle. There is an answer, and it's just a couple of numbers.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Actually, judging by the K&R book, this function really must never crash. But by the ANSI C standard, the behavior in the particular crashing case is undefined, and with x86 compilers it crashes.

Comment: Does undefined mean that it doesn't crash?  Or does it mean that it's the implementations choice how to handle such things?  Does the C standard preclude signed integers from being represented by ones' complement?

Comment: Undefined means it's implementation dependent, and may return any value, crash, or format your hard disk. The C standard says that if the result of division can't be stored in an integer (which is the case here), behavior is undefined.

Comment: The FAQ is quite clear that puzzle on this site are expected to have an objective criteria for determining a winner. A "give me a list of examples" type problem does not qualify because all examples are equally valid.

Comment: @dmckee, If you give the right answer, you're the winner. What cretirion could be more clear and objective? There's only one answer (or do you have another example?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-2147483648 (INT_MIN) and -1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int f(int x, int y) {
    return (y==0) ? 0 : (x/y);
}
int main() {
    int r = f(INT_MIN, -1);
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

$ gcc -Wall division.c && ./a.out # => zsh: floating point exception  ./a.out

Comment: Indeed. Though this should give a warning, because 2147483648 isn't a valid integer.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used INT_MIN after, to use a valid int. I guess the reason is 2147483648 is not a valid int, since INT_MAX is 2^31-1 with 32-bit int.

Comment: Ah.  Two's complement.  I missed that.

Comment: Yes, it should compile cleanly with INT_MIN (which is -2147483648).

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is already given, but I immediately thought about [Microsoft Pex](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/).

> Pex automatically generates test suites with high code coverage. Right
>   from the Visual Studio code editor, Pex finds interesting input-output
>   values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with
>   high code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a Visual Studio add-in for
>   testing .NET Framework applications

After [adding your puzzle](http://www.pexforfun.com/default.aspx?language=CSharp&code=jQDsvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1StfgdKEIgGATJNiQQBDswYjN5pLsHWlHIymrKoHKZVZlXWYWQMztnbz33nvvvffee__997o7nU4n99%2f%2fP1xmZAFs9s5K2smeIYCqyB8%2ffnwfPyLWTbG8SF9fN22_OExSevif1XpSFtN0WmZNk76sq4s6W6S%2fmL_yXzZt1tKPYtmmL9c%2f_EGZb_HXdyP_5PqObZ6mdd6u62W6df3ZZzt30t8j3UkfpVvv7l7fOdQmv4R%2f%2fpL%2fJwAA%2f%2f8%3d) in the sandbox site, it finds the answer in a few seconds, the same as eregons answer. (click ask pex)

*Note: it does it in C#, but the language is not really relevant.*

- x: int.MinValue
- y: -1
- Exception: OverflowException
- Message:
  Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: Nice. It surely doesn't brute-force it, because it wouldn't end in a few seconds. I guess someone in MS realized that numbers around 0 and MAX_INT are always interesting.

Comment: Hopefully it's a little more clever than that. It might look at `(x/y)` and know that `INT_MIN`, `-1`, `0` etc. are all problem cases for that expression, and try to reverse engineer a way to produce those values at the time of evaluation.